# How can I display a Regexp output in an Alphabetical list?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to coding and new to learning the language Ruby. I've made progress on my code of a letter histogram. I'm now at a point where I'm struggling.

```
class Letter

  def initialize
    @text = "Hello, World!"
    @letters = Hash.new(0)
  end

  def calculateFrequencies
    @text = text.downcase.chars.each do |c|
      next if c =~ /\s/
      @letters[c] += 1
    end
    puts(@letters)
  end

  def Display

  end 
end
```

I have created an application that will accept a user input message, process it and output a list of letters with a number to represent how often that letter appeared in the user's message.
I would like the output to list the entire alphabet, and use * to represent how often that letter was used.

For example:

```
A: **** (For being used 4 times) 
B: ** (For being used 2 times) 
C: (Even if it wasn't used) 
D: * (For being used once) ... and so on all the way to letter Z.
```

This is my current output for "This is a test":

```
irb(main):019:0> h.calculateFrequency 
{"t"=>3, "h"=>1, "i"=>2, "s"=>3, "a"=>1, "e"=>1}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should [write a title that summarizes the specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This title is extremely vague and does not explain what this question is about; this title is instead about your desire to get help with Ruby, which we can safely assume already since you are posting a question on a site exclusively about help with programming. Please take a moment to click the _edit_ button below your post and rephrase your question's title to reflect the content of your post after reading the article I linked to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you construct your class as follows.

```
class Letter
  def initialize(text)                                  # 1
    @text = text
  end

  def display
    h = calculate_frequencies                           # 2
    ('a'..'z').each { |ltr|
      puts "%s%s" % [ltr, '*' * h.fetch(ltr, 0)] }      # 3
  end

  private                                               # 4

  def calculate_frequencies                             # 5
    @text.downcase.
          each_char.                                    # 6
          with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, letters|       # 7
            letters[c] += 1 if c.match?(/\p{Lower}/) }  # 8
  end
end
```

```
str = "Now is the time for all Rubyists to come to the aid of their bowling team."

ltr = Letter.new(str)
ltr.display
a***
b**
c*
d*
e******
f**
g*
h***
i******
j
k
l***
m***
n**
o*******
p
q
r***
s***
t********
u*
v
w**
x
y*
z
```

**Notes**

**1**

`text` should be an argument of `initialize` so the methods can be used for any string, rather than for just one hard-wired string. `@letters` should not be initialized here as it needs to be initialized in `calculate_frequencies` each time that method is called (and there it need not be an instance variable).

**2**

For `str`, `calculate_frequencies` returns

```
ltr.send(:calculate_frequencies) 
  #=> {"n"=>2, "o"=>7, "w"=>2, "i"=>6, "s"=>3, "t"=>8, "h"=>3, "e"=>6,
  #    "m"=>3, "f"=>2, "r"=>3, "a"=>3, "l"=>3, "u"=>1, "b"=>2, "y"=>1,
  #    "c"=>1, "d"=>1, "g"=>1}
```

[Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-send) invokes `private` methods, as well as ones that are `public` or `protected`.

**3**

See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) and [String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-2A).

**4**

All methods defined after the invocation of the keyword `private` are private, until and if the keyword `public` or `protected` is encountered. Alternatively, one can define a single private method as `private def calculate_frequencies; ... ; end`. Also a public (or protected) method `m` may be made private by executing `private m`.

**5**

One of Ruby's conventions is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of variables and methods. You don't have to follow that convention but 99%+ of Rubyists do.

**6**

[String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chars) returns an enumerator, whereas [String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chars) returns an array. The latter should only be used when an array is needed or it is chained to an `Array` method; otherwise, `each_char` is preferable because it does not create an unneeded temporary array.

**7**

See [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).

**8**

Rather than matching everything other than spaces, you probably want to only match letters. Note how I've used `if` here to avoid the need for two statements. See [String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F). One could instead write `c =~ /\p{Lower}/` or `c[/\p{Lower}/]`. `\p{Lower}` (or `[[:lower:]]`) matches any Unicode lower-case letter, which generally is preferable to `/[a-z]/`. Even for English text, one may encounter words having letters with diacritical marks, such as née, Señor, exposé and rosé. `"é".match? /[a-z]/ #=> false` but `"é".match? /\p{Lower}/ #=> true`. Search the doc [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) for `\p{Lower}` and `[[:lower:]]`.

Comment: how would you do this without pre-defining the string first, the way I have it now uses hello world as a standard string if nothing is set, then once set will take any input as a string. I'm now after getting it to display the alphabet with * next to each character to represent the amount used

Comment: You could do that in various ways, though it would be an odd thing to do. One is to add `@text = "Hello, World!"` to `initialize` and remove that method's argument, as you have in the question. Even simpler would be to replace `@text` in my method `calculate_frequencies` with `"Hello, World!"` and remove the method `initialize`.

Comment: I've tried using the structure and the code example that you have given me and I'm getting a lot of syntax errors

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it's my understanding that  `"%string" % [stuff]` is no longer the preferred way to do string formatting, and `format("%string", stuff)` is considered better, partly because  it is a bit more clear about what the arguments are, and you don't have to put them in an array...

Comment: @Garrett, I was not aware of that, and see no mention of it in the [Ruby Style Guide](https://shopify.github.io/ruby-style-guide/). Do you have a citation?

Comment: I forgot where I heard that, so sadly no, @CarySwoveland. Google was no help in finding it. Basically, the criticism I remember boiled down to the weirdness of passing multiple arguments to a binary operator, and that it is overly terse and not very intention revealing. Wish I could find that citation...

Comment: @Garrett, if `h = {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}` and `s = "%s=>%d"`, `h.each {|k,v| puts format(s, k, v)}`, `h.each {|a| puts format(s, *a)}` and `h.each {|a| puts s % a}`  all print the same two lines, `"a"->1` and `"b"=>2"`. I don't really see much difference among them. Note that only one argument is passed to `%`. Also,  "Somewhere I read that.." is not especially authoritative. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Good start :)

In order to make a method private, place it after a call to `private` in the class:

```
class foo
  # all methods are public by default
  def something_public
    # …
  end

  private
  # makes all methods after this call private
  def something_internal
    # …
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can call private with the symbol name of the method you want to make private (after it has been defined): `private :something_internal`. In newer versions of ruby defining a method returns the method name (as a symbol), so you can also do this:

```
private def something_internal
  # …
end
```

to make just the one method private.

In ruby, "private" means that you can't call the method with a dot, e.g. `foo.something_internal` will raise a `NoMethodError` if `something_internal` is a private method on `foo`. That means that to call a private method, you need to be in a method in the same class:

```
class foo
  # …

  def something_public
    if something_internal # method called without a dot
      'the internal check was truth'
    else
      'the internal check was falsey'
    end
  end

  # …
end
```

Private methods are usually used to create helpers for the class that don't make sense to be called from outside the class, or that can cause bugs if they are called at the wrong time. In ruby, you can call a private method anyway if you really want by using send: `foo.send(:something_internal, 'some', 'arguments')`. But generally, you shouldn't need to, and you should rethink your code and see if you can refactor it to not need to call send.

Also, by convention in ruby, method names are `snake_cased` and usually don't start with a capital (although the language allows this).